# How to remove value by id from JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have small project where I need to be able to insert/edit/delete records from JSON file. I use `http://myjson.com/` API for this project (not sure if this is the best solution maybe some other sources API's are better). I'm trying to remove record from json file and I'm not sure how to do that. Is there any way to do that with this API? There are instructions on how to add/update records to the json file but none on how to remove record. Here is my code example:

```js
var contactStorage = {};

/*** Start: Build Datatables function. ***/
function buildDataTable(tblID, columnsArray, displayLength) {
  $('#' + tblID).DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ],
    "iDisplayLength": displayLength,
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
      'bSortable': false,
      'aTargets': columnsArray
    }],
    "language": {
      "emptyTable": "No records were found."
    }
  });
}
/*** End: Build Datatables function. ***/

/*** Start: Phone number format for US standard. ***/
$('.us-phone').on("keypress", formatPhoneUS);

function formatPhoneUS(e) {
  var output,
    inputVal = $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''),
    area = inputVal.substr(0, 3),
    pre = inputVal.substr(3, 3),
    tel = inputVal.substr(6, 4);

  if (parseInt(inputVal, 10)) {
    if (area.length < 3) {
      output = "(" + area;
    } else if (area.length === 3 && pre.length < 3) {
      output = "(" + area + ")" + " " + pre;
    } else if (area.length === 3 && pre.length === 3) {
      output = "(" + area + ")" + " " + pre + "-" + tel;
    }
  }

  if (e.key === 'Backspace') return;

  $(this).val(output);
};
/*** End: Phone number format for US standard. ***/

$("#frm_find").on("submit", findContacts);

function findContacts(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var frmFilter = $("#frm_filterby").val();

  if (frmFilter) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/7iig8?' + new Date().getTime(),
      dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(obj) {
      contactStorage = obj.filter(function(entry) {
        switch (frmFilter) {
          case '1':
            return entry.status === 1;
            break;
          case '2':
            return entry.status === 0;
            break;
          default:
            return entry;
        }
      });

      showContacts(contactStorage);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert('Error: ' + errorThrown);
    });
  }
}

function showContacts(contactStorage) {
  var contactsTbl = "<table id='contactsTbl' class='table table-bordered'><thead><tr><th>Last</th><th>First</th><th>Email</th><th>Phone</th><th>Status</th><th class='text-center'>Edit</th><th class='text-center'>Delete</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

  if (contactStorage) {
    for (var key in contactStorage) {
      contactsTbl += "<tr id='" + $.trim(contactStorage[key].id) + "'><td>" + $.trim(contactStorage[key].last) + "</td>";
      contactsTbl += "<td>" + $.trim(contactStorage[key].first) + "</td>";
      contactsTbl += "<td>" + $.trim(contactStorage[key].email) + "</td>";
      contactsTbl += "<td>" + $.trim(contactStorage[key].phone) + "</td>";
      contactsTbl += "<td>" + $.trim(contactStorage[key].status === 1 ? 'Active' : 'Inactive') + "</td>";
      contactsTbl += "<td class='text-center'><button class='btn btn-default btn-sm contact_edit' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#save_contact,#search_contact'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></button></td>"
      contactsTbl += "<td class='text-center'><button class='btn btn-default btn-sm contacts_delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button></td></tr>";
    }
  }

  contactsTbl += "</tbody></table><div class='row'><div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12'><div id='contact_message' class='alert message-submit'></div></div></div>";
  $('#contacts_list').empty().append(contactsTbl).show();
  buildDataTable('contactsTbl', [5, 6], 10);
}

var deleteID, targetTr;
$("#contacts_list").on("click", ".contacts_delete", displayContact);

function displayContact() {
  deleteID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'), // Get record ID.
    targetTr = $(this).parents('tr');

  var lastName = targetTr.find("td").eq(0).text(),
    firstName = targetTr.find("td").eq(1).text(),
    bodyContent = $('<p>You are about to delete record for <b>' + lastName + ', ' + firstName + '</b>.<p>Do you want to proceed?</p>');

  $('#delete_modalBody').empty().append(bodyContent); // Append elements to body content.
  $('#deleteModal').modal('show'); // Show delete modal box.
}

$("#deleteModal").on("click", ":button.confirm_delete", removeContact);

function removeContact() {
  if (deleteID) {
    var table = $("#contactsTbl").DataTable(); // Select DataTable by ID.
    table.row(targetTr).remove().draw(); // Remove record from DataTable.
    delete contactStorage[deleteID]; // Remove element from JS object.

    $("#contact_message").show().addClass("alert-success").html("Record successfully removed.").delay(5000).fadeOut('slow').queue(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("alert-success").dequeue();
    });
  } else {
    $("#contact_message").show().addClass("alert-danger").html("Error! Please contact your administrator.").delay(5000).fadeOut('slow').queue(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("alert-danger").dequeue();
    });
  }
}
```

```css
div.container {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Contact Application</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- *** Start: JS and CSS for DataTables. *** -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />
  <!-- *** End: JS and CSS for DataTables. *** -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="App.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Welcome to Contact Application</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="search_contact" class="collapse in">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#save_contact,#search_contact">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> New Contact
                                </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <form name="frm_find" id="frm_find" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="row find-row">
              <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2">
                <select class="form-control" name="frm_filterby" id="frm_filterby" required>
                  <option value="">--Choose--</option>
                  <option value="1">Active</option>
                  <option value="2">Inactive</option>
                  <option value="3">Show All</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2">
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="frm_search" id="frm_search">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
                                    </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          <div id="contacts_list" class="table-responsive"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="save_contact" class="collapse">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#save_contact,#search_contact">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left"></span> Go Back
                                </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <form name="frm_contacts" id="frm_contacts" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="fname"><span class="label label-primary">First Name:</span></label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frm_first" id="frm_first" placeholder="Enter First Name" maxlength="50" title="A-Z, space, dash, apostrophe, period, comma - no other special characters" pattern="[a-zA-Z][A-Za-z' .,-]{0,49}$" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="lname"><span class="label label-primary">Last Name:</span></label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frm_last" id="frm_last" placeholder="Enter Last Name" maxlength="50" title="A-Z, space, dash, apostrophe, period, comma - no other special characters" pattern="[a-zA-Z][A-Za-z' .,-]{0,49}$" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="email"><span class="label label-primary">Email address:</span></label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="frm_email" id="frm_email" placeholder="Enter Email" maxlength="80" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group required">
              <label class="control-label" for="phone"><span class="label label-primary">Phone:</span></label>
              <input type="tel" class="form-control us-phone" name="frm_phone" id="frm_phone" pattern="\(\d{3}\)[ ]?\d{3}[-]?\d{4}" maxlength="14" title="US based Phone Number in the format of: (xxx) xxx-xxxx" placeholder="(xxx) xxx-xxxx" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group required">
              <label class="control-label" for="status"><span class="label label-primary">Status:</span></label>
              <select class="form-control" name="frm_status" id="frm_status" required>
                <option value="">--Choose--</option>
                <option value="1">Active</option>
                <option value="0">Inactive</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                <button type="submit" name="frm_submit" id="frm_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-11 col-lg-11">
                <div id="frm_message" class="alert alert-Submit"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <p><span>© 2018 MD. All Rights Reserved.</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="deleteModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Delete</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="delete_modalBody"></div>
        <div class="modal-footer" id="delete_modalFooter">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning confirm_delete" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script language="javascript" src="App.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If anyone knows how this can be achieved or some other API's that can be used for this purpose please let me know.

Comment: First of all if there's nothing preventing you from saving to a file then you should save to a local file. However you can just get the json, run javascript's [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) and then make a PUT request to update the JSON.

Comment: @Aplet123 Are you talking about saving json file to local server? Regarding the solution, first remove element from object then upload file back to API, correct?

Comment: Yeah basically.